# Pass a C Structure from Python using Ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to call a function in a C library that uses a structure as a parameter. How do i do this? I have created the Ctypes representation of the structure similar to what is done in the documentation but i passing it directly doesnt work.

I have tried to find examples but all the examples I found were passing in pointers to structures.

Comment: You really need to provide some sort of test case and what error you're getting.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is that the function takes an entire structure as a parameter (e.g. `foo(struct mystruct bar)`) instead of a pointer. I don't know if that's supported in `ctypes`. You could try to emulate it by passing a bunch of arguments, but that's very fragile and depends on calling convention. Best to write a Cython wrapper or something.

Comment: @nneonneo: Passing vanilla structures by value is fine. The problem, per issues [16575](http://bugs.python.org/issue16575) and [16576](http://bugs.python.org/issue16576), is passing unions, structures with bitfields, and packed structures on x86-64.

Comment: @eryksun: That is my question. How do i pass a structure by value? Lets say the structure i want to pass is a POINT, how would i do that?

Comment: Let's call it `Point`. Put it in the function pointer's `argtypes`, e.g. `lib.foo.argtypes = [Point]`. Then `p = Point(10, 20); lib.foo(p)`. Passing a small structure like this on the stack is reasonable. Typically for larger structures you'll need a pointer, e.g. `lib.bar.argtypes = [POINTER(SomeBigStructure)]`. Then `sbs = SomeBigStructure(); lib.bar(byref(sbs))`.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but my guess is that you have to instantiate the structure.  From the docs:

```
from ctypes import *

class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
                ("y", c_int)]

point = POINT(10, 20)
```

The last line makes an instance of the POINT structure called point.

It would really help if you could show the structure definition, how you're using it, and any error messages

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem.  I have a C libxxxx.so file and the corresponding .h files.  That is it. Several of the function prototypes defined in the first .h file require the passing in of a structure on the stack. The structure is defined in the second .h file. I looked at the usb1 Python library wrapper and every single structure is passed as a pointer to the function prototypes. (Some even as pointers to pointers.)

I made a wrapper for this struct:

```
typedef struct _SE_ADDR{
   int slot;   /**< The index of the target slot. */
   int fpga;   /**< The index of the target FPGA. */
   int reg;    /**< The index of the target register. */
} SE_ADDR;
```

In the Python wrapper module, I made a class to represent this struct:

```
class SE_ADDR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('slot', c_int),
                ('fpga', c_int),
                ('reg', c_int)]

SE_ADDR_p = POINTER(SE_ADDR) #Pointer to SE_ADDR required for se_waitForData_new
```

Then after importing the wrapper I used it the way @picomancer described above:

```
addr = wrapper.SE_ADDR(0,0,0)
```

This appears to work.